# Finding the length of a radius knowing only length of external tangent

Tags: geometry

In the figure below I only know that the length of $PA$ and $BA$ are $4$. I also know that $PA=PA'$ and that $AB = A'B'$. How can I find the length of the radius of the smaller circle?

[image]

Comment: Hint: let the radius of the small circle be $r\,$, then the radius of the large circle will be $2r$ (*why?*). The distance between the centers of the two circles is $3r$ (*why?*), now find a second way to calculate the same distance, and you get an equation in $r\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like $PB$ and $PB'$ are the common tangent lines of the two circles (although this is not stated explicitly, but I will assume this).

First, let $R$ denote the radius of the larger circle and $r$ that of the smaller one. Also, let $O$ denote the center of the smaller circle, and $O'$ that of the larger one. Find $C$ on $O'B$ such that $OC\perp O'B$. Then it is easy to see that

(i) $R=2r$;

(ii) $OO'=R+r$;

(iii) $O'C=r$.

Then consider the right triangle $\triangle OCO'$. Applying the Pythagoras theorem on this triangle, we obtain that $|OO'|^2=|O'C|^2+|OC|^2$, that is 
$$(3r)^2=4^2+r^2,$$
from which we can solve $r=\sqrt 2$.